# How to do this discrete math problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Construct a sequence of $16$ positive integers that has no increasing or decreasing subsequence of $5$ terms.

I know the answer but I fail to see how it is arrived at.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly due to Erdős–Szekeres theorem this sequence must have an monotonic subsequence of length $4$. So the first idea shall be dividing the numbers into groups of size $4$.
WLOG assume the 16 numbers to be $1,2,...,16$.
Then group them like the following:
$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$,
$B=\{5,6,7,8\}$,
$C=\{9,10,11,12\}$,
$D=\{13,14,15,16\}$
Now if they don't come in the order $D,C,B,A$ it will surely have an increasing subsequence of length $5$.
So we set them like $D,C,B,A$ and it's easy to check that it's true, too.

Comment: Can’t seem to understand this. :/

Comment: What seems to be the problem

Comment: “Now if they don’t come in the order DCBA, it will surely have an increasing subsequence of length 5.” This part.

Comment: Each of the groups A,B,C,D are a subsequence of length 4. They don't come in the order D,C,B,A ; I'll there will be a bigger element of the biggest element of one group after it, which makes an increasing subsequence of length 5. For example if C comes after B , there will be 9 after the subsequence {5,6,7,8} which makes an increasing subsequence of length 5

Comment: Can you illustrate with an example please?

Comment: The last part is the example :) let's say your order is D,B,A,C. Then the element {9} which is in C is coming after B which is {5,6,7,8} and thus, these five will make an increasing subsequence of length 5

Comment: Oh okay. I don’t know how I misinterpreted your statements somehow, so I got confused.

Comment: So the answer can be 13,14,15,16,9,10,11,12,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4 and also 4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5,12,11,10,9,16,15,14,13?

Comment: Using the partitioning I used for the 16 elements, the only answer will be 13,14,15,16,9,10,11,12,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4 which is a valid answer. Furthermore, there may very well be more answers by using different groupings but you just asked for the motivation of reaching one valid example. And yes, clearly if you turn any valid answer backwards it will still be a valid answer due to the fact the condition still holds under turning the sequence backwards.